# Woocommerce Deleted Products Variations Remain

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I have recently added the WP All Exports Plugin to my Wordpress site and exported a list of all the products from my woocommerce store.

I have noticed that I have in excess of 100 Variants on the CSV file shown which the Parent Product has been deleted.
The variation appears to still be in my Database however the parent Product is not.

Has anyone else experienced this? is there a way that I can clear out the database and get rid of these variations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should first delete all variations in a variable product, before deleting it, as product variations are just a post like products.

**Hopefully** there is an option in woocommerce **to delete Orphaned variations**.

It's located in Woocommerce > Status > Tools tab:

[image]